# Managing Connections in an Azure Serverless Function App

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, serverless

[Microsoft recommends](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.cosmosclient?view=azure-dotnet) you maintain a single instance of CosmosClient across your whole application, and I'm trying to achieve this in my Function App (with more than just CosmosClient). However, even when re-using both database & container proxies, I always see a warning that I have hit the maximum (10) number of connections to Cosmos and that it's discarding the connection when I send through enough requests.

For context, it's a serverless Python Function App triggered by a message queue, the connections are managed in shared code in a helper function. I have to use the Cosmos SDK because I have to both read and update Cosmos doc.

Has anyone successfully navigated this in the past? would it simply be best practice to instantiate a new connection for *every single function call*? I tried creating a new CosmosClients when receiving burst traffic, but proved very difficult to do efficiently.

Here's an example of the class I'm using to manage connections:

```
COSMOS_CLIENT = None

class Client:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cosmos_client: CosmosClient = self._get_global_cosmos_client()
    
    def _get_global_cosmos_client(self) -> CosmosClient:
        global COSMOS_CLIENT
        if COSMOS_CLIENT is None:
            logging.info('[COSMOS] NEW CLIENT CONNECTION')
            COSMOS_CLIENT = CosmosClient.from_connection_string(COSMOS_DB_CONNECTION_STRING
        return COSMOS_CLIENT
```

Comment: Can you share code snippets on how you are creating the client?

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta I sure can! Updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually, because you are creating the client based on ConnectionString (there is always 1) this code should always create 1 client.

The number connections is not the number of clients.

Do not create multiple clients, always create 1 client for each account you are interacting against. That single client can perform operations on all existing databases/containers in the account.

Creating multiple clients just creates a problem, because each client will maintain its own independent connections and not reuse them and it will create a higher number of connections than reusing the single client, eventually leading to SNAT port exhaustion.

The error message: `Connection pool is full, discarding connection:` is not generated by the Cosmos Client directly, rather from the underlying `urllib3.connectionpool`. See: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/12102

The CosmosClient supports passing the session through `transport`,  https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/core/azure-core/CLIENT_LIBRARY_DEVELOPER.md#transport, -> https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/cosmos/azure-cosmos/azure/cosmos/_cosmos_client_connection.py#L198.
Reference: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/12102#issuecomment-645641481

Comment: The warning comes from cosmos, it's likely making too many connections to Cosmos over HTTP. I have updated the sample code to show how I was originally instantiating the client. It only creates one client, and it hits the max connections almost instantly.

Comment: Can you please share the exact warning message details?

Comment: Also, how is the code guarding against concurrent calls to `_get_global_cosmos_client`?

Comment: Here is the exact warning
`Connection pool is full, discarding connection: cosmosdbname-eastus.documents.azure.com. Connection pool size: 10`

As far as concurrent calls, I did not think that the GIL would allow that within a single function.

Comment: See edited answer. This is not coming from Cosmos, it is coming from `urllib3`

Comment: Ah, I see. The GH issue you linked is related to a queue storage container, not a cosmos container. When I pass the session keyword to the cosmos container, like `CosmosClient.from_connection_string(COSMOS_DB_CONNECTION_STRING, session=sess)`, I get `request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'session'`. Otherwise this seems like the solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251873/discussion-between-hunter-boyd-and-matias-quaranta).